# Intl converted value ( Currency ) is not working in Textinput

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
    
export default class TabScreen extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
     number:''
    }

  }

 onChangeNumber(value){
    var number = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(value) ;
    this.setState({number:number.toString()})
 }



  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(value) => onChangeNumber(value)}
        value={this.state.number}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
       />
      </View>
     )
  }
}
```

Error : After comma or separtor textinput showing NaN Value.From react-native above 0.60 intl is now integral part of android.I tried to convert values in string using inbuild method and also tried number conversion nothing works.Everytime after 3 digit the value of textinput showing NaN value

Answer (score 0):

Just use this library,

react-native-currency-input (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-currency-input)

```
npm i react-native-currency-input
```